# can I script leaving/joining a domain (and not have to reboot)?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I've been getting this message a lot lately:

[image: The Security database on the server does not have a computer account for this workstation trust relationship]

I'm building a few Windows VMs. The fix is to leave the domain and then rejoin it. It's a bit labor intensive though... is there any way to do this via script and not have to reboot in the middle? Doing it the manual way takes about 3-5 mins.

Comment: Actually the fix is to make them not change their computer account password and make it not expire.  On my phone or I would look up the procedure for that.

Comment: How are you building these VM's? Are you using a template VM of some sort?

Comment: Yes, typically cloning an existing VM, renaming the machine, leaving domain, rejoining domain. Even with that, I still get cryptic AD messages from time to time.

Comment: You should sysprep your clone/template. Then use it to deploy new virtual machines. You'll avoid this problem completely.

Comment: @joeqwerty Because of the new...ish sysyprep/rearm limits added to Windows OSes, it's often better to do a scripted sysprep of new machines after they're cloned, rather than having to worry about how many times your template/source VM has been sysprepped.

Answer (score 5):

No, you cannot avoid the reboot.  You can script the joining and disjoining of a domain, but you're solving the wrong problem.

The proper approach is not to clone domain-joined VMs in the first place.  Create a template of a VM that is in a workgroup, rather than a domain, then rename and domain-join it once it's finished cloning/deploying from a template.

And, as noted by Big Chris in the comments below, don't forget to sysprep, provided you want things like Windows Update and SCCM to work properly.

Comment: Even better would be to use any of the automated scripted deployment tools in your template and avoid "cloning" the vm in the first place

Comment: Don't forget to sysprep as well to remove SIDs... Or does this not matter with workgroup clones (that will eventually be domain joined)?

Comment: @BigChris [Actually, SID duplication being a problem is a myth](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/11/03/3291024.aspx), but there are other really good reasons to use sysprep. I suppose I should mention that. Thanks!

Comment: Great article. Just sat and read the lot ;) I think ANYONE doing image deploying should do sysprep regardless of whether it's actually necessary. At the end of the day, especially with Win 7/8, it is the easiest final step of the process and it'll let you (much more easily) standardise the image for multiple hardware profiles. Plus WIM's are blummin' useful too! Off on a tangent there but great article and very useful answer :)